# Python scikit learn multi-class multi-label performance metrics?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision, multilabel-classification

I ran Random Forest classifier for my multi-class multi-label output variable. I got below output.

```
My y_test values


     Degree  Nature
762721       1       7                              
548912       0       6
727126       1      12
14880        1      12
189505       1      12
657486       1      12
461004       1       0
31548        0       6
296674       1       7
121330       0      17


predicted output :

[[  1.   7.]
 [  0.   6.]
 [  1.  12.]
 [  1.  12.]
 [  1.  12.]
 [  1.  12.]
 [  1.   0.]
 [  0.   6.]
 [  1.   7.]
 [  0.  17.]]
```

Now I want to check the performance of my classifier. I found that for multiclass multilabel "Hamming loss or jaccard_similarity_score" is the good metrics. I tried to calculate it but I was getting value error.

```
Error:
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

Below line I tried:

```
print hamming_loss(y_test, RF_predicted)
print jaccard_similarity_score(y_test, RF_predicted)
```

Thanks,

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to implement this yourself if it is not supported in the library.

Answer (score 7):

To calculate the unsupported hamming loss for multiclass / multilabel, you could:

```
import numpy as np
y_true = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3]])
y_pred = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
np.sum(np.not_equal(y_true, y_pred))/float(y_true.size)

0.75
```

You can also get the `confusion_matrix` for each of the two labels like so:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, precision_score
np.random.seed(42)

y_true = np.vstack((np.random.randint(0, 2, 10), np.random.randint(2, 5, 10))).T

[[0 4]
 [1 4]
 [0 4]
 [0 4]
 [0 2]
 [1 4]
 [0 3]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 3]]

y_pred = np.vstack((np.random.randint(0, 2, 10), np.random.randint(2, 5, 10))).T

[[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 4]
 [1 4]
 [0 4]
 [0 3]
 [1 4]
 [1 3]
 [1 3]
 [0 4]]

confusion_matrix(y_true[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0])

[[1 6]
 [2 1]]

confusion_matrix(y_true[:, 1], y_pred[:, 1])

[[0 1 1]
 [0 1 2]
 [2 1 2]]
```

You could also calculate the `precision_score` like so (or the `recall_score` in a similiar way):

```
precision_score(y_true[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0])

0.142857142857
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to get confusion matrix for such output.

Comment: this syntax doen't work for multiclass-multioutput.  I am getting an error   ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can get a confusion matrix for each of the two labels. None of the `sklear.metrics` currently supports multioutput-multiclass classification out of the box.

Comment: Thanks thats useful

Comment: Please let me know if this doesn't answer your question and you need more info.

Comment: I got this output when I ran your code. I don't know how to interpret this result. How do I know  the precision and recall   for each class

Comment: First Label         
   `[[1 0]
     [0 1]]`
    
  second label  
   `[[1 0]
     [0 1]]`

Comment: I've added an example on how to calculate the `recall_score` for the first label.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if your question has been addressed.